# jQuery $.grep filtering array

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, filter, autocomplete

Hey all I have the following array:

```
classifieldData = [{
    value: 'Afghana fghani',
    type: 'For Sale',
    location: 'Somewhere',
    category: 'Automotive - Motorcycle',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    img: 'http://placehold.it/35/FF0000'
},
{
    value: 'British pound',
    type: 'For Sale',
    location: 'Vegas',
    category: 'Automotive - Vehicles',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    img: 'http://placehold.it/35/FFFF00'
},
{
    value: 'United States dollar',
    type: 'Wanted',
    location: 'Vegas',
    category: 'Automotive - Motorcycle',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    img: 'http://placehold.it/35/00FF00'
},
{
    value: 'United States dollar',
    type: 'Wanted',
    location: 'Texas',
    category: 'Automotive - Motorcycle',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    img: 'http://placehold.it/35/00FF00'
},
{
    value: 'Uruguayan peso',
    type: 'Wanted',
    location: 'Vegas',
    category: 'Automotive - Vehicles',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    img: 'http://placehold.it/35/00FFFF'
},
{
    value: 'Uzbekistan isom',
    type: 'For Sale',
    location: 'Somewhere',
    category: 'Automotive - Vehicles',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    img: 'http://placehold.it/35/0000FF'
},
{
    value: 'Vanua tuvatu',
    type: 'Wanted',
    location: 'Somewhere',
    category: 'Automotive - Vehicles',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    img: 'http://placehold.it/35/808080'
},
......etc etc
```

And this is the jQuery code I am using to filter:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: get_classifields(false, false, false),
    minChars: 1,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + 
                             suggestion.value + ' <br> <strong>Symbol:</strong> ' + 
                             suggestion.data + ' <br> <strong>Url:</strong> ' + 
                             suggestion.url;
        $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
    }
});

$("#autocomplete").focusin(function() {
        //compile filter here
        var count = 0;
        var _data = "";
        var tmp1 = false;
        var tmp2 = false
        var tmp3 = false;
        
        $('span[id="search_concept"]').each(function() {
            _data = $(this).attr("data-selected");
        
            if (count == 0) {
                if (_data != "NA") {tmp1 = true;};
            } else if (count == 1) {
                if (_data != "NA") {tmp2 = true;};
            } else if (count == 2) {
                if (_data != "NA") {tmp3 = true;};
            }
            
            count++;
        });
        
        //console.log(tmp1 + "|" + tmp2 + "|" + tmp3);
        
        $('#autocomplete').autocomplete('clear');
        
        $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
            lookup: get_classifields(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3),
            minChars: 1,
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + 
                                     suggestion.value + ' <br> <strong>Symbol:</strong> ' + 
                                     suggestion.data + ' <br> <strong>Url:</strong> ' + 
                                     suggestion.url;
                $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
            }
        });         
    });

function get_classifields(check_type, check_location, check_category) {
    found_classifields = $.grep(classifieldData, function(v) {
        console.log(v.type + "|" + v.location + "|" + v.category);
    
        return (!check_type || v.type === v.type) && 
               (!check_location || v.location === v.location) && 
               (!check_category || v.category === v.category);
    });
            
    console.log(check_type + "|" + check_location + "|" + check_category);
    console.log(found_classifields);
    return found_classifields;
}
```

The **get_classifields** is passed 3 *true* or *false* depending on if the user has selected anything from the **3 select dropdown boxes**:

[image]

Now I know my JavaScript logic is incorrect as it sits. It's just compering the same values against each other (**Wanted === Wanted**). So no matter what the user selects from the 3 select dropdowns, its always going to have the same amount of classifieds without filtering some out.

So as an example of what I am looking to do:

Say the user selects the following:

> (1)Wanted
>
> (2)Vegas
>
> (3)Automotive - Vehicles

When the user starts typing in the search box and types a **Ur** it should come up with only one result - **Uruguayan peso**.

But like I said above, its only bring all of them back no matter what's being chosen in the 3 select boxes.

I may very well be just over-thinking this but how can I accomplish this without the need to hard-code the values? (ex: **v.type === "For Sale"**)?

Here's the full example in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/0xysh9wh/1/) that I am currently working with.

Comment: your fiddle yields a `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function` error on console.

Comment: @MithunSreedharan Hum... im not getting an error?

Comment: Since you are trying to debug a filter....strip out everything except the data and your filter function. Far less time consuming than having to make it work in autocomplete UI with multiple other selections. Get better response too. People like playing with arrays...but not when in complex UI